# Why reading data from localdb (MssqlLocalDb) via Entity Framework 6 works only via named pipes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

As the title says: if I create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model in an ASP.NET MVC website and set the connection via db instance it says

> Test connection succeeded

while debugging the code where I read a table it gives me an error

> underlying connection failed to open

If I change the connection string from this (instance)

```
<add name="GameDbEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GameDb.csdl|res://*/Models.GameDb.ssdl|res://*/Models.GameDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=GameDb;user id=codadmin;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

to this (named pipe)

```
<add name="GameDbEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GameDb.csdl|res://*/Models.GameDb.ssdl|res://*/Models.GameDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D6BBC602\tsql\query;initial catalog=GameDb;user id=codadmin;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

it works as expected, it reads data from the db

I don't understand this,because if I create a wpf application it works just out of the box via the instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL Server Express. The problem is that, with this SQL Version, TCP/IP connection are by default disabled.

Few steps to activate it :

- Go to  SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols
- Enable TCP/IP

More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention I use SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB...
BTW I have installed SSMS 2016 
I see nothing under "SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit)"
While under "SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32Bit)" I see "client protocols", here TCP is enabled :

  -  Default port: 1433
  -  Enabled: Yes
  -  Keep alive: 30000
  -  Keep alive Internal: 1000